# Python - finding words based on repeated characters specified in a string

Tags: python, string, character

Let's say I have a list of words:
resign
resins
redyed
resist
reeded

I also have a string ".10.10"

I need to iterate through the list and find the words where there are repeated characters in the same locations where there are numbers in the string.

For instance, the string ".10.10" would find the word 'redyed' since there are e's where there are 1's and there are d's where there are 0's.

Another string ".00.0." would find the word 'reeded' as there are e's in that position.

My attempts in python so far are not really worth printing.  At the moment I look through the string, add all 0s to an array and the 1s to an array then try to find repeated characters in the array positions.  But it's terribly clumsy and doesn't work properly.

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag it as such.  If not, maybe you can tell us more about the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def matches(s, pattern):
    d = {}
    return all(cp == "." or d.setdefault(cp, cs) == cs
               for cs, cp in zip(s, pattern))

a = ["resign", "resins", "redyed", "resist", "reeded"]
print [s for s in a if matches(s, ".01.01")]
print [s for s in a if matches(s, ".00.0.")]
```

prints

```
['redyed']
['reeded']
```

Comment: You can use the same `if` as the filtering condition of the generator expression instead of using it for a ternary expression.

Comment: @agf: The ternary expression wasn't necessary, you are right.  I edited my answer about the same time you commented, but your solutions sounds even nicer.

Comment: @Acorn I don't really think so. This way, the `or` is checking for the truth of the condition, and then `all` is checking it again -- if you use `for ... in ... if condition` then it only gets checked once. None of it is really important as the `setdefault` doesn't get evaluated unless the condition is `True` for any of the three methods.

Comment: Anyway, this solution is clean and is exactly what I needed.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @agf: Thinking about your last comment, I realized that `all(condition(x) for x in a)` is always equivalent to `all(False for x in a if not condition(x))`.  It feels a bit strange for me to use filtering here.

Comment: `all(cp == "." or d.setdefault(cp, cs) == cs
               for cs, cp in zip(s, pattern))` seems less natural to me than `all(d.setdefault(cp, cs) == cs
               for cs, cp in zip(s, pattern) if cp != ".")`, both because of the double-testing I mentioned before and because of the logic of it. A `.` isn't logically a `True`, it's a lack of any test at all, which is what you get with the filtering condition.

Comment: @agf: Well, you are right, this seems to be a very natural way to look at this.